# Very slow internet on Sony VAIO, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, performance, lag

I am on a university connection plugged into the wired connection. About 50% of the time I am using my computer, my internet runs very slowly. It takes me ages to buffer any streaming videos online, my Xbox can barely run Xbox Live, and any games on my computer are lagged.

I run Windows 7. My roommate plugs into a different ethernet jack in the wall and his connection is great.

Comment: If you connect to the same jack as your roommate, do you get the same performance as he does?

Answer (score 1):

The possible causes such as registry corruption, overload browser pages, too many useless junks/temporary files, caches & errors, system activity traces etc. The fact is, you should keep some maintenance job regularly. See more info:

[How to make your computer run faster: 6 tips to increase PC speed](http://www.microsoft.com/atwork/maintenance/speed.aspx)